# How to open/maximize a function or class in Visual Studio using keyboard

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment

We generally minimize or shrink a function or class by clicking

> -

symbol on left corner of every function in Visual Studio.
I want do with keyboard instead of mouse.
How can that be done.

Answer (score 2):

CTRL-M CTRL-M

Alternatively, you can open up Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and assign "Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion" to any keyboard combo you like.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Will. I found there are Shotrcut for selected command- Text Editor and Database Warehouse Designer(DWD), Where the DWD i used?

Comment: @yaj I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: In the picture that you have uploaded, you can see "Shortcuts for selected command:". In that there is default "Ctrl+M Ctrl+M (Text Editor)" and there is another item in same dropdown as Database Warehouse Designer. My Question is that For what purpose this Database Warehouses Designer used.

Comment: @Yaj for designing Database Warehouses http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244687(VS.80).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You just hit Ctrl-M, Ctrl-M to toggle outlining.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want ctrl-M, O and ctrl-M, L.  These keys will close and open all regions in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl M + Ctrl M does the trick

Answer (score 0):

It should also be mentioned that you don't have to click on the - itself...anywhere in the vertical bar below will do it. That makes it easy to quickly shrink successive methods since the next method's vertical bar tends to come up under your mouse pointer after you shrink the one above it.